# What is the difference between reboot , init 6 and shutdown -r now?

Tags: linux, shutdown, init, reboot

I just want to know difference between in

- `reboot`
- `init 6`
- `shutdown -r now`

and which is the safest and the best?

Comment: The exact behavior of these three commands varies from operating system to operating system.

Comment: Related: [“reboot” or “shutdown -r now”: what restart command is safer?](https://serverfault.com/q/787144) (on SF)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

There is no difference in them. Internally they do exactly the same thing:

- `reboot` uses the `shutdown` command (with the -r switch). The shutdown command used to kill all the running processes, unmount all the file systems and finally tells the kernel to issue the ACPI power command. The source can be [found here](http://util-linux.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.14/shutdown_8c-source.html).
  In older distros the reboot command was forcing the processes to exit by issuing the `SIGKILL` signal (still found in sources, can be invoked with `-f` option), in most recent distros it defaults to the more graceful and init friendly `init 1 -> shutdown -r`. This ensures that daemons clean up themselves before shutdown.
- `init 6` tells the `init` process to shutdown all of the spawned processes/daemons as written in the init files (in the inverse order they started) and lastly invoke the `shutdown -r now` command to reboot the machine

Today there is not much difference as both commands do exactly the same, and they respect the init scripts used to start services/daemons by invoking the shutdown scripts for them. Except for `reboot -f -r now` as stated below

There is a small explanation taken from manpages of why the `reboot -f` is not safe:

```
  -f, --force
    Force immediate halt, power-off, reboot. Don't contact the init system.
```

Edit:

Forgot to mention, in upcoming RHEL distributions you should use the new `systemctl` command to issue poweroff/reboot. As stated in the manpages of `reboot` and `shutdown` they are "a legacy command available for compatibility only." and the `systemctl` method will be the only one safe.

Comment: Sometimes my reboot hangs at the SIGTERM, is there a way to know why, and also is there a way to timeout the reboot, such that if it takes too long, it will force a reboot?

Comment: Those RHEL versions are no longer "upcoming".  ☺  As explained in more detail at http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196014/5132, on such systemd operating systems there's no difference at all.  They aren't even different programs.

Comment: Did you typo by saying `init 1 -> shutdown -r`?

Comment: Your link is broken.

Answer (score 18):

Shutdown is preferable because it allows you to specify the *reason* for the drastic action -- something you should always do. The message will be recorded in the log(s) for posterity. For example:

`shutdown -r now 'Kernel upgrade requires reboot'`

You can also perform a *scheduled* reboot -- by specifying something other than `now` as the reboot time:

`shutdown -r 22:00 'Work around kernel memory leak'`

Then your users will get periodic reminders to get out as the time approaches -- the process will be more orderly and professional.

Comment: I'd recommend "reboot" not to have someone by accident shut down their remote server without it starting up again.

Answer (score 7):

On FreeBSD there is a difference between `reboot` and `shutdown -r now`. From the `reboot` man page:

> Normally, the shutdown(8) utility is used when the system needs to be
>        halted or restarted, giving users advance warning of their impending doom
>        and cleanly terminating specific programs.

Comment: This is not a BSD question, though, as evidenced by the tag on the question and use of a System 5 run-level in one of the commands.  ☺

Comment: I know it is a Linux question. I thought someone might find it useful to know that on some other systems the is a difference.

Comment: I came here looking for the answer for BSD, and glad to see it here, even if BSD isn't Linux.

Answer (score 5):

On traditional unices, `reboot` and `shutdown -r now` are vastly different commands.  Under typical usage, `reboot` is only safe to use in single user mode.

`shutdown -r now` is the canonical method to shutdown across different *nix's and safer to use in general and is functionally equivalent to `init 6`.

[init(8)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=init&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%209.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html)
[reboot(8)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=reboot&sektion=8&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%209.1-RELEASE)