# Rebooting fails randomly

Tags: linux, arm, reboot

That is, the following command fails at times:

```
$ sudo reboot
```

The last message on terminal, after which the machine gets stuck, requiring a power cycle:

```
Restarting system.
```

I tried the following `reboot=` boot parameters ([source](http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7009779)) without success:

- warm
- cold
- triple
- acpi
- force
- efi

As advised on that page, I verified by running the following command to ensure the changes took effect:

```
$ cat /proc/cmdline
```

In case it might be helpful, here's a list of kernel modules:

```
$ lsmod 
Module                  Size  Used by
ppp_generic            16680  0 
slhc                    4055  1 ppp_generic
ath9k_htc              50685  0 
mac80211              231186  1 ath9k_htc
ath9k_common            1720  1 ath9k_htc
ath9k_hw              338115  2 ath9k_htc,ath9k_common
ath                    13793  3 ath9k_htc,ath9k_common,ath9k_hw
cfg80211              158343  3 ath9k_htc,mac80211,ath
compat                 29364  5 ath9k_htc,mac80211,ath9k_common,ath9k_hw,cfg80211
```

This is on an ARM system, running a custom-built Linux **2.6.35**. Also, there is no X server installed, so no Desktop Environment.

Comment: Do the system logs say anything of relevance?

Comment: @Tshepang - you could try one of the kernel `"reboot="` [parameters](http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7009779) (many similar cases are "cured" with `reboot=pci`; YMMV).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Which logs must I look at? `/var/log/syslog` looks fine.

Comment: Just wondering: does "sudo shutdown -r now" work the same (i.e. doesn't work :)?

Comment: @Bob same issue.

Comment: This could be (sound like) a *BIOS bug*. Did you try to upgrade your BIOS to latest version?

Comment: @F.Hauri could be a U-Boot issue, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually [an age-old fix](http://git.freescale.com/git/cgit.cgi/imx/linux-2.6-imx.git/commit/?h=imx_2.6.35_maintain&id=8e03278824625e8d528e129ad49e094e4d533f87) for this particular issue of mine. I wish I could have (magically) known about it before <strike>wasting</strike> spending so much time on it.

As a sidenote, the system is [a VAB-800](http://www.viaembedded.com/en/products/boards/1930/1/vab-800.html), which uses a Freescale i.MX537 Cortex-A8 SoC.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few ways:

```
sudo reboot
```

```
sudo init 6
```

```
sudo /sbin/reboot
```

You may also like to give this a try

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq

echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

If you've got freedesktop-compliant session manager, you can use DBus to invoke restart from inside the X session. The command goes:

```
dbus-send --system --dest=org.freedesktop.Hal --type=method_call \
    --print-reply /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer \
    org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.SystemPowerManagement.Reboot int32:0
```

(this is probably more than necessary; works for me). I use this in a shell script. You don't need to run this from `root`, but you need to run it from inside an X session (f.e. in a terminal). You can find more on this topic at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingGNOMEPowerManager

If you still get the problem , show the output of the `last reboot` command which will show a log of all reboots since the log file was created under Linux, enter:

```
# last reboot
```

I think the problem may be due to this [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=141102) and this [bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=25522) . Try upgrading your kernel by following the method :

## Upgrade of the kernel in Debian or Ubuntu Linux

Use `apt-get` command. First find your kernel version:

```
$ uname -r
```

Next find available kernel images:

```
$ apt-cache search linux-image
```

Now install kernel by explicitly specifying version number:

```
# apt-get install linux-image-x.x.x-xx
```

OR

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-x.x.x-xx
```

## update:

After doing this you may also   try setting the `reboot=pci` kernel boot flag .
To make the change permanent, add the `rebooot=pci` flag to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` line of `/etc/default/grub`.
For more information check out this [link](http://www.andrewbolster.info/tag/linux/) and this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7114/why-cant-i-restart-shutdown)

Comment: I don't run X, so no session manager.

Comment: What about the other options ? Have you tried them all . And what is your output of `last reboot`

Comment: `last reboot` gets me entries looking like `reboot   system boot  2.6.35.3-1129-g6 Mon Jul  1 07:54 - 07:55  (00:00)`, whether or not I had a failing reboot.

Comment: I have also tried `sudo init 6`, and saw the same issue. Lemme try `/sbin/reboot`.

Comment: Basically last reboot shows that whether your previous reboot was successful or not .That is it tells at what time and date last successful reboot was done .

Comment: `/sbin/reboot` fails too.

Comment: In that case, `last reboot` claims the reboot was successful, even though it wasn't.

Comment: @Tshepang : I think the problem is due to a bug.Try Upgrading the kernel using the method . Do check the updated answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9467/discussion-between-tshepang-and-tushar-makkar)

Answer (score 2):

It **might** be time to consider grabbing the bull by the horns and learn some kernel debugging.

First, find a JTAG probe that's compatible with gdb-remote. You're using an ARM, so you should have many options, for example see http://openocd.sourceforge.net/doc/html/Debug-Adapter-Hardware.html

Secondly, there's work... "man up" on Kernel Debugging. Google is your friend, but this one provides an excellent initial overview and some search terms: http://www.elinux.org/DebuggingTheLinuxKernelUsingGdb

You could have many new concepts to absorb. This video provides a good high-level view of the process: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q07VvWS1qBc

http://www.wikihow.com/Solve-a-Problem has great advice on solving tough problems. GL!

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement. Me loves the *man* and *bull* references :)

Comment: @Tshepang haha - that "man" has more to do with "manual" :) Also, you might find the linux-arm-kernel mailing list handy http://www.arm.linux.org.uk/mailinglists/lists.php 
Also, take a look at this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64280/what-is-the-difference-between-reboot-init-6-and-shutdown-r-now

Answer (score 1):

Here's something to explore/check. I found this bit in a [commit log for the ARM Tegra commit log for kernel version 2.6.39](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/linux/kernel/1356508):

> Simon Glass (1): 
>   ARM: tegra: Fix hang on reboot

I think this is the patch that Simon's commit, titled: [[PATCH 7/7] ARM: tegra: fix hang on reboot](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.ports.tegra/250), is referring to:

```
From: Simon Glass <sjg@...>

We cannot use writel() here since the resulting wmb() calls l2x0_cache_sync()
which uses a spinlock and L1 cache may be off at this point.

Signed-off-by: Simon Glass <sjg@...>
Signed-off-by: Olof Johansson <olof@...>
---
 arch/arm/mach-tegra/common.c |    2 +-
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)

diff --git a/arch/arm/mach-tegra/common.c b/arch/arm/mach-tegra/common.c
index 34559d1..b1ecf60 100644
--- a/arch/arm/mach-tegra/common.c
+++ b/arch/arm/mach-tegra/common.c
 <at>  <at>  -41,7 +41,7  <at>  <at>  void tegra_assert_system_reset(char mode, const char *cmd)

    reg = readl(reset);
    reg |= 0x04;
-   writel(reg, reset);
+   writel_relaxed(reg, reset);
 }

 static __initdata struct tegra_clk_init_table common_clk_init_table[] = {
--
```

I think you'll either need to backport this change to 2.6.35 or move up to the newer kernel.

#### References

- [Index » linux : Commit 375b19](http://git.opencores.org/?a=commit&p=linux&h=375b19cd34ea9b1ab338deac20b4bd2c553bf57b)

Comment: Sadly, I don't have such a directory. [My system](http://www.viaembedded.com/en/products/boards/1930/1/vab-800.html) has a `Freescale i.MX537 Cortex-A8` processor. Searching the kernel sources, there is not even a `write1_relaxed` function.

Comment: @Tshepang - Can you provide us with a list of the kernel modules you have loaded? I'm thinking that one of these drivers is the culprit.

Comment: I updated the Question.

Comment: @Tshepang - does the problem persist if you manually unload the ath9k* modules? If wouldn't mind testing out this hypothesis I'd appreciate it. You'll need to manually unload it each time you're about to test this.

Answer (score 1):

See Freescale application note "Using Open Source Debugging Tools for Linux on i.MX Processors" http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/app_note/AN4553.pdf

Especially Chapter 8 - "First Steps for Using KGDB for Linux Kernel Debug"

There is a patch for Freescale Linux kernel which allows serial port kernel debugging - https://gist.github.com/bikeNomad/4033368.

Some kernel hackers swear they can figure anything with printk. See http://www.linuxchix.org/content/courses/kernel_hacking/lesson5

Comment: Tshepang - were you able to hunt down the bug?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80855

Answer (score 0):

Try `init 6` instead of `reboot`.

Comment: I see the same problem... it fails to reboot sometimes, forcing a power cycle.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a *BIOS* issue.

You may try to

- upgrade your BIOS (from constructor website)
- run linux in disabling some bios features at boot command line, like `noapic`, `vga=0x0f00`, `pci=nobios` or else...

To find *whats' wrong*, browsing log are usefull, but not only the logs where the system hangs, but reading logs where all was perfect could help too:

One way could be to run a kind of loop, where you

- reboot
- mark the kernel.log : `echo >>kernlogpos.lst $(wc -l </var/log/kern.log) Ok|Bad`
- loop

After some loop with and without bug you may obtain a trace file that look like:

```
19845 first
20451 Ok
21057 Ok
21676 Bad
22282 Ok
22888 Ok
```

Than you could search for difference (using bash):

```
diff <(
  sed -ne </var/log/kern.log '21057,21676{s/^.\{15\}\s\S\+\skernel:\s\[\S\+\]\s//p;}'
  ) <(
sed -ne </var/log/kern.log '21676,22282{s/^.\{15\}\s\S\+\skernel:\s\[\S\+\]\s//p;}'
)
```

Good luck!