# reboot in the middle of the script

Tags: scripting, reboot

I see `sudo reboot` in the middle of a script - meaning there are more commands after it. Is there any situation when the commands after `reboot` can be executed, assuming that `reboot` is not within an `if` block?

Following is the portion of the script with `reboot` in it. Note that there is no `if` block involved.

```
    sudo sysctl -p # applies sysctl.conf changes
    sudo sed -i "s/#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0/ListenAddress 0.0.0.0/" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    sudo service ssh restart

    sudo reboot

    echo "postfix postfix/main_mailer_type        select  No configuration" | sudo debconf-set-selections
    echo "gridengine-master       shared/gridenginemaster string  hpc-master" | sudo debconf-set-selections
    echo "gridengine-master       shared/gridenginecell   string  default" | sudo debconf-set-selections
    echo "gridengine-master       shared/gridengineconfig boolean false" | sudo debconf-set-selections
    echo "gridengine-common       shared/gridenginemaster string  hpc-master" | sudo debconf-set-selections
    echo "gridengine-common       shared/gridenginecell   string  default" | sudo debconf-set-selections
    echo "gridengine-common       shared/gridengineconfig boolean false" | sudo debconf-set-selections
    echo "gridengine-client       shared/gridenginemaster string  hpc-master" | sudo debconf-set-selections
    echo "gridengine-client       shared/gridenginecell   string  default" | sudo debconf-set-selections
    echo "gridengine-client       shared/gridengineconfig boolean false" | sudo debconf-set-selections
    sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install gridengine-common gridengine-client gridengine-master -y
    sudo -u sgeadmin /usr/share/gridengine/scripts/init_cluster /var/lib/gridengine default /var/spool/gridengine/spooldb sgeadmin
    sudo service gridengine-master restart
    sudo service postfix stop
    sudo update-rc.d postfix disable
```

Comment: Please include the relevant lines from the script in question, a lot will depend on the details.

Comment: When I am working on my machine, I have noticed that I can still get in a few commands after I have given it the `reboot` command.

Comment: I found a similar script at https://github.com/pdonald/linux-scripts/blob/master/ubuntu-gridengine.sh except it has comments. I think it is a concatenation of scripts to do various useful things rather than a single script meant to be executed all at once. Can you tell us the source of the script in your question?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I was referring to the same script. I took out the comments just to highlight the relevant part. It seems that I misunderstood the purpose of that file. I thought there is some trick to get the part past `reboot` executable. It is an odd way of organizing scripts, though.

Answer (score 2):

The script will continue if `sudo` fails, for instance if the user doesn't have appropriate permissions in `/etc/sudoers`.

The command could also be inside an `if` block. Other parts of the script would be executed if the condition is not true.

Comment: `shutdown -c` will cancel a pending shutdown - which is one way the `reboot` as opposed to the `sudo` command could fail.

Comment: @emory When `reboot` invokes `shutdown`, does it specify a default delay? I don't see any mention of it in the man page.

Comment: But does the _reboot_ command wait while this happens? I think _shutdown_ returns immediately, after forking a background process to do all the work.

Comment: This http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64385/17964 suggests `reboot` should have the same behavior as `shutdown`